# Can Communication or Mind Reading be used to speak with someone who doesn't share a language with you?

Tags: languages, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, telepathy

I'm looking at the [Psychic's](http://www.d20herosrd.com/character-creation/archetypes/psychic/) Telepathy Power. It's functionally two powers. It's the [Communication](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/communication-sensory/) power and [Mind Reading](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/mind-reading-sensory/) power. The mind reading power does not require the [Comprehend](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/comprehend-sensory/) power to understand thoughts in another language. Because the powers are linked, does the Psychic character not need the Comprehend power to telepathically speak to someone who does not share a language with them?

However, if the character does require the Comprehend power, how many ranks should they take in order to have their telepathy understood and understanding any responses they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Psychic does not need Comprehend to understand the people linked via Communication - Mind Reading ensures the Psychic can understand everyone in the link.

The targets have no such benefit. They need either a common language or a Comprehend power to be involved for the communication to be two-way. The other characters linked by Communication **do not** have Mind Reading, so they don't inherently understand the thoughts being projected. "Telepathy" allows the Psychic to understand the surface thoughts of anyone within a mile, and send her own thoughts to those people but those people don't necessarily understand the Psychic.

 If the Psychic has one rank of Comprehend (speak any language) then she should be able to communicate clearly to everyone within the mile radius area.

Comment: So the response does not count as a "surface thought".

Comment: @MnIce The non-psychics are using their "surface thoughts" to talk to the Psychic. And the Psychic is sending out her surface thoughts with Communication - but the non-psychics have to have the ability to understand the language of those thoughts. Comprehend, Feature, or a common language are all sufficient.

Comment: Hmmm... the rules do say that "surface thoughts" don't count as language, although as a GM, I feel like that means that that communication is not exact in that case without a shared language, e.g. someone trying to tell you that the password is "*pomme de terre*" may result in a non-French-speaking mind-reader instead thinking the password is "potato". It's an interesting wrinkle.